# Use object as a dictionary or list in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, underscore.js

I currently store my data in AngularJS as lists. Such as:

```
var users = [{id: 1, name: "Mary"}, {id: 2, name: "John"}];
```

This however leads to for-loops whenever I want to change something.

```
function gotChangesFromServer(data) {
    for (var i=0; i < users.length; ++i) {
        if (users[i].id == data.id) {
            users[i] = data;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I was looking into underscore.js and found it has some nice functions like values() to get a list of values from a dictionary-like structure. So I could instead do:

```
var users = { "1": {id: 1, name: "Mary"}, "2": {id: 2, name: "John"} };

function gotChangesFromServer(data) {
    users[data.id] = data;
}

function getUsers() {
    return _.values(users);
}
```

But, I realized that AngularJS will call my getUsers() function a lot. On every filter operation or any change to the data.

So it seems I have to choose between two bad solutions. Either for-looping all the time when changing the users, or accessing a user based on id. Or, calling values() often, which I suppose, basically is a for-loop over the properties in the users object.

I expect to have around 1000 - 5000 users in the users list / dictionary.

How would you do it?

Comment: Can't you simply assign users = data and let angular loop over the new array when $digest'ing ?

Comment: Add `users = _.values(users);` to the end of `gotChangesFromServer`?

Comment: Also this really depends on what you want to do functionally, if you're only displaying 10 users at a time you shouldn't even have to care about this

Comment: I have about 1000 - 5000 users in the list. Not displaying all of them, but they are searchable etc.

Comment: Can't you save for users in a map structure as in `users = {1: 'Mary', 2: John}` that way is much more straight forward to search for a user in particular.

Comment: Do you have any control of the service that the Users are returned to angular? If so, I would have the users serialized as a dictionary   {"1": {"name": "Mary"}, "2": {"name":"John"} }

Comment: Martin: Yes, I do have control of the data and could return it in any way which is most suitable. Returning it as a serialized dictionary would still not solve the issue of having to call _.values() multiple times during filtering.

Comment: Have you tested how the "naive" implementation performs first? You shouldn't worry about premature optimization too much...But if you are really concerned, what about keeping different data structures for different purposes? A plain list/array for filtering, and a more complex structure for updating. And only when you update the complex structure you rebuild the array.

Comment: link: No I haven't measured it, but looping through thousands of items to find the correct one... hurts inside me ;) But your idea of having two data structures is a good idea. (Well - one data structure would be ideal, but seems that I can't have that)

Comment: `hurts inside me` AngularJS itself does crazier things under the hood.If you do not notice specific performance issues you shouldnt worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use underscores `findWhere`method to retrieve certain objects:

```
_.findWhere(users, {id: 123}).data = newDataForThisUser;
```

Your `gotChangesFromServer` would then look like this:

```
function gotChangesFromServer(data) {
  _.extend(_.findWhere(users, {id: data.id}), data);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I still need the index to replace the item in the array?

Comment: with `findWhere` you have allready retrieved the item from the array. So you don't need the index anymore. See this gist for an example: https://gist.github.com/nikolassv/3bc68fad87434b785d00 (run the code on a page where underscore.js is loaded)

Comment: Your solution works when there is only one property (name), but I have more properties for each user, which I don't want to iterate over to set.

Comment: luckily, underscore also has a method to achieve that: `_.extend()`. I edited the example in my answer so that you can change more than one property at the time.